# Time Capsule / AirPort Extreme Wi-Fi Signal

Tags: wifi, airport, time-capsule

Regard maximizing the Time Capsule or AirPort Extreme Wi-Fi signal, just for my curiosity and knowledge, from the hardware standpoint why is not recomended to place the Time Capsule or AirPort Extreme in areas surrounded by **metal surface on three or more sides**?

Answer (score 1):

Radio waves (your WiFi signal) are blocked/reflected by metal surfaces.

If you surround the antenna with metal surfaces on 3 sites you will get very limited reception.

Using that factor one can build a directional antenna that works in one direction and magnifies the signal.

If you have a TV dish that is how it works, it is a directional antenna that reflects the signal to a receiver mounted in the focal point.

So if you want to boost your Airport signal you would use a directional antenna. As it is right now it has a signal that is 360 degree.